# How to document @return if there is more than one possible return statement?

Tags: java, documentation, return

How is this method to be documented? The return depends on the result of the if statement.
Do I have to write down both possible returns and how should it look like?

```
/**
 * [...]
 *
 * @throws java.io.IOException 
 * @return aktivesKonto The Konto we looked for.
 * @return null If there wasn't an aktivesKonto
 */
public Konto getKonto(String kontonummer) throws java.io.IOException {

    if(...){
        System.out.println(...);

        return null;
    }
    else{

        return aktivesKonto;
    }
}
```

thank you.

Comment: Do it in single return annotation `@return the Konto we looked for, or {@code null} if <description of your condition>`

Answer (score 0):

see example at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html

```
/**
 * Returns an Image object that can then be painted on the screen. 
 * The url argument must specify an absolute {@link URL}. The name
 * argument is a specifier that is relative to the url argument. 
 * <p>
 * This method always returns immediately, whether or not the 
 * image exists. When this applet attempts to draw the image on
 * the screen, the data will be loaded. The graphics primitives 
 * that draw the image will incrementally paint on the screen. 
 *
 * @param  url  an absolute URL giving the base location of the image
 * @param  name the location of the image, relative to the url argument
 * @return      the image at the specified URL
 * @see         Image
 */
 public Image getImage(URL url, String name) {
        try {
            return getImage(new URL(url, name));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reader will read the documentation like,
If you write `return null`, you are not returning `null` but you are returning `object Konto`  with value `null`.

and refer the coding standard If possible to keep only one `return` statement as below, its recommended.

```
public Konto getKonto(String kontonummer) throws java.io.IOException {

   Konto aktivesKonto=null;

    if(...){
        System.out.println(...);


    }
 return aktivesKonto;
}
```

so in if statement if you assign some value of `Konto` it will return same otherwise `null`